# Beautiful soup on heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, beautifulsoup, virtualenv

I was trying to deploy an application using Beautiful soup on heroku and run a command like "python manage.py " . My command uses Beautiful soup library. Though the command works perfectly on my local machine but it couldn't find beautiful soup module on heroku. I tried to install it using pip install beautifulsoup, then adding it to requirements file and pushing the updates using git. But still it cannot find beautiful soup module. I know it is little specific and I am new to heroku, django. I am not sure how to debug it? Can anybody guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to use BeautifulSoup 4, you have to add that version explicitly:

```
$ pip install beautifulsoup4
$ pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.1.3
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: You should create a `requirements.txt` file and add beautifulsoup4 to it. Heroku will install everything from your requirements file automatically on a deploy.

Comment: They said they added it to the requirements file, perhaps they named it something else.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Maybe this will be helpful: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa I checked by uninstalling and reinstalling, but still the same error. Any pointers on where I can look?

Comment: Is your requirements.txt file at the root of your project? Have you committed it to git

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa Yeah, did that, just figured out the problem was with importing instead of from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup , I needed to do from bs4 import BeautifulSoup . Although, I was using the former on the local machine and it worked perfectly.